# Dot Counter issue

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment that requires me to write a program that counts the dots in an input line. So far this is what I have came up with it works (sort of)except that it is counting everything instead of only the dots. I am stuck with how to make the program to only count the dots.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Assign5_Polk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give me dots and i will count them : ");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            if (string.contains(".")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are" + " "+ count + " " + "dots" +" " + "in this string. " + string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (string.contains("."))
```

This line is checking the whole string and returning true if there is a `.` anywhere in it.

Instead, you want to test if `c` is a `.`

Answer (score 2):

Change the `if` condition as below :

```
if (string.contains(".")) { // Check whole String contain dot
 count++;
}
```

to

```
 if (c == '.') { //Check single char of String contain dot
     count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you repeatedly test if the entire *string* has dots, and increment the counter each time. You need something like `if (c == '.')` instead, to determine if the character you are looking at is a dot.

Comment: Since `char` is primitive, you just want `c == '.'`, not ".equals".

Comment: char dont have equals method

Comment: If you edit your post the downvoters may remove their bad votes.

Comment: @Christian To keep things clear for OP, `equals()` can be used with all objects (not just strings), and not with primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Solution **without** loop ;-)

```
 count = string.replaceAll("[^.]","").length();
```

This makes your program pretty short:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give me dots and i will count them : ");
    int count = string.replaceAll("[^.]","").length();
    System.out.println("There are "+ count + " dots in this string: " + string);
}
```

Comment: @user3380392 Did you give it a try?